# Is SSRS supported with Azure database?

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

We are planing to move our on premise database to Azure DB. We have SSRS reports as well. Is there any solution with Azure database for SSRS?

Comment: Read from an Azure SQL Database as a data source or host the SSRS DB on the Azure Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately SSRS is not supported on Azure SQL Database. If you need SSRS it makes more sense to use a SQL VM on Azure or a SQL Server instance on-premises.

In [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140523110804/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj992719.aspx#bkmk_ssrs_nativemode) URL you will find deployment strategies for SSRS on Azure SQL VM.

You can deploy SSRS to a VM and use Azure SQL Database as the data source, but maybe is cheaper to have your databases  on the same SQL VM.

Once you deploy the VM containing SSRS, you can then connect SSRS to an Azure SQL DB. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/sql-azure-connection-type-ssrs?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) article discusses connecting Azure SQL Database to SSRS.

If you want to vote for SSRS to be offered as PaaS service please vote [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/18964057-ssrs). However, [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/7955331-support-sql-server-reporting-service) Microsoft states is not planning to add SSRS to Azure SQL Database in the future.